# Can I add a component to a specific grid cell when a GridLayout is used?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout, jpanel

When I set the GridLayout to the JPanel and then add something, it is added subsequently in the "text order" (from left to right, from top to bottom). But I want to add an element to a specific cell (in the i-th row in the j-th column). Is it possible?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, you can't add components at a specific cell. What you can do is add empty JPanel objects and hold on to references to them in an array, then add components to them in any order you want.

Something like:

```
int i = 3;
int j = 4;
JPanel[][] panelHolder = new JPanel[i][j];    
setLayout(new GridLayout(i,j));

for(int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
   for(int n = 0; n < j; n++) {
      panelHolder[m][n] = new JPanel();
      add(panelHolder[m][n]);
   }
}
```

Then later, you can add directly to one of the JPanel objects:

```
panelHolder[2][3].add(new JButton("Foo"));
```

Comment: Or, if you are not tied to `GridLayout`, you can use [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 9):

Yes

```
    import java.awt.GridLayout //Grid layout from awt docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,1,1));
    JButton component= new JButton("Component");
    panel.add(component, 0,0 );
```

**Create your panel and set its layout.**
*new GridLayout(numberOfRows,numberOfColums,HorizontalGap,VerticalGap)*
(new GridLayout(2,2,1,1))  => here i want 2 rows, 2 columns, 
 - if any horizontal gaps (HGap), they should be 1px (1unit)
 - I also want the same for vertical gaps so i do same as vertical gaps(VGap). i.e 1 unit

 - In this case; gaps  =>  spacing/margins/padding --in that sense.

**Create your components and add them to the panel**

 - (component, 0,0 )  => 0,0 is the row and column.. (like a 2d array). @row 0 & @column 0 or at intersection of row 0 and column 0

specify where your component goes by putting the row and column where it should go. 
each cell has a location == [row][column]

Or you can do it without hgaps and vgaps:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();        
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JButton component= new JButton("Component");
    panel.add(component, 0,0 );
```

Comment: Regarding both examples if i use `panel.add(component, 1,1 );` I get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position`

Comment: it still works fine for me.. what version of java are you using?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html
make sure your GridLayout is from awt

Comment: the second parameter (`constraints`) is ignored, the third parameter (`index`) determines the index at which it will be inserted (same ordering as elements are added using the 1-argument `add`) (( `panel.add(component, 1, 1)` do the same as `panel.add(component, null, 1)` or `panel.add(component, 99, 1)` ))

Comment: the documentation link posted is for the GridLayout. to see the docs for JPanel you can use this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html