# Gridbag layout or Grid layout?

Tags: java, swing

I am a little new to swing.  In order to learn to use the API correctly, I am designing the following project:
The project is a solving block puzzle solver sliding block puzzle similar to the rush-hour puzzles common in toy stores - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_(board_game) except there is no escape for a special car.

By dragging the blocks from an off board area to the board, the user specifies the starting configuration of the puzzle.  The user, in the same way, specifies an ending goal configuration which dictates where some (or all) of the blocks the user specified initially must be at the end of the puzzle - the ending configuration can be specified using only SOME of the blocks, making multiple legal ending configurations.

The algorithm for solving the puzzle is already complete - I just need to design the interface and I am getting stuck.  For designing the tray, I used a grid layout.  Since blocks need to be entered at certain positions, I need to be able to place blocks in specific cells in the grid and move them around.

A 'block' object has four attributes - its height, width, its top row, and its left most column (ie - each block is addressed by its top left corner).

I used the suggestion here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510159/can-i-add-a-component-to-a-specific-grid-cell-when-a-gridlayout-is-used ) for the grid layout.

Right now I have only programmed to the point where java reads the puzzle from a .txt file and is supposed to display it on the screen ( I have not designed any user interactablity yet ).

First, here is the code I have written so far.

```
public class SolverPuzzleGUI extends JFrame {

//Specs from the puzzle.
Board initBoard;
ArrayList<Block> goalBlocks;
LinkedList<Move> moveList;

JLayeredPane layeredpane;
JPanel Board;
Dimension boardsize = new Dimension(400, 500);
JPanel[][] panelHolder = new JPanel[5][4];

public SolverPuzzleGUI(Board startBoard, ArrayList<Block> startGoalBlocks,
        LinkedList<Move> startMoveList) {
    this.initBoard = startBoard;
    this.goalBlocks = startGoalBlocks;
    this.moveList = startMoveList;


} // end constructor.


//gives the actual simulation

public void runSimulation() {



    // Initalizing the main window.
    setSize(500, 600);
    setName("Solution");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(getMinimumSize());



    //Using layered pane
    layeredpane = new JLayeredPane();
    add(layeredpane);
    layeredpane.setPreferredSize(boardsize);

    layeredpane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    layeredpane.setVisible(true);



    // adding the game tray
    Board = new JPanel();
    layeredpane.add(Board, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    Board.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));

    // centering the game tray.
    Board.setPreferredSize(boardsize);
    Board.setMinimumSize(boardsize);
    Board.setMaximumSize(boardsize);

    Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    box.add(Board);
    box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

    add(box);


    //Adding placeholders to the board for  creating blocks
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            panelHolder[i][j] = new JPanel();
            panelHolder[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

            Board.add(panelHolder[i][j]);
            layeredpane.setLayer(panelHolder[i][j], JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
            panelHolder[i][j].setVisible(false);


        } // end 'j' for
    } // end 'i' for

    ArrayList<Block> initBlocks = initBoard.getBlocks();
    //int count = 0; //DEBUG
    for (Block block : initBlocks) { 
        this.drawBlock(block);
        //count++;
        //if(count > 4) { break; }
                } // end 'for'


    Board.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    Board.setVisible(true);

    setVisible(true);
} // end 'run'



private void drawBlock(Block block) {
    Dimension blockSize = new Dimension(block.getWidth()*100, block.getHeight()*100);
    System.out.println(blockSize.width);
    System.out.println(blockSize.height);

    JPanel screenBlock = new JPanel();

    screenBlock.setPreferredSize(blockSize);
    screenBlock.setMinimumSize(blockSize);
    screenBlock.setMaximumSize(blockSize);
    screenBlock.setSize(blockSize);

    screenBlock.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    screenBlock.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    layeredpane.setLayer(screenBlock, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER);

    int leftRow = block.getRow();
    int leftCol = block.getColumn();


    panelHolder[leftRow][leftCol].setSize(blockSize);
    panelHolder[leftRow][leftCol].setVisible(true);
    panelHolder[leftRow][leftCol].add(screenBlock);
    layeredpane.setLayer(panelHolder[leftRow][leftCol], JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER);


    screenBlock.setVisible(true);



}// end 'drawBlock'






public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = "C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\init.from.handout.txt";
    String goal = "C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\goal.2.from.handout.txt";

    /*
    A SolverPuzzle object is the object which actually solves the algorithm -
    when the class is constructed, it takes the file path of the inital 
    configuration as an input, as well as the file path of the goal
    configuration.  It has the following fields:

    A 'board' object which specifies the inital configuration of the board.
    It contains an ArrayList of Block objects(Remember block objects store 
    the height and width of the block, as well as the address of the 
    top left corner of block) which specify the starting
    blocks, an ArrayList of EmptySpace objects which specify the empty 
    spaces on the board, an ArrayList of Move objects, which contain 
    the legal moves of the configuration, and the height and width of
    the tray (in this application, the tray will always be 5 x 4).

    An ArrayList of Block objects which specify the ending configuration.

    A LinkedList of Move objects which specify the shortest possible
    list of Moves which brings the configuration to a position which
    satisfies the goal position.  A Move object has three fields - 
    The block object being moved, and the row and column of the 
    top left corner of the block in the new position.  


    */

    SolverPuzzle test; 
    try { test = new SolverPuzzle(file, goal); }
    catch (IOException ex) { 
        System.out.println("IOException");
        return;
    }
    Board testBoard = test.getStartBoard();

    ArrayList<Block> testGoalBlocks = test.getGoalBlocks();
    LinkedList<Move> testMoveSolution = test.getMoveList();

    // testing the gui
    SolverPuzzleGUI testGUI = new SolverPuzzleGUI(testBoard, testGoalBlocks,
                                testMoveSolution);
    testGUI.runSimulation();

}

} // end class 'SolverPuzzleGUI'
```

Here's the current output vs desired output.

## https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyngy.jpg

So specifically, I have two questions:

1 - Why is the image only showing the top left corners of the blocks instead of the whole block?

2 - Is it better to continue using the GridLayout or switch to GridBagLayout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` would definitely be suitable for want you want to do. For example, you can expand components to envelop more than one column or row - just like what you want to do. Check out the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for how to use them.

A key point to remember when using `GridBagLayout`is that you need to reset the `Constraints` after each component, assuming that they're unique to that particular component.

Also - I can't discern what you mean by only showing the top-left - it looks likes its showing the whole thing to me...

Comment: The problem I have with GridBagLayout is that there seems to be no way to make the grid a static size - that is, how do I make it so it is always a 5 x 4 grid, and the grid does not add or remove columns when I'm applying moves to the board.

Also, when I run the code, it only shows the top left corner.  For instance, the center block is supposed to span 2 columns and 2 rows and the top left corner of the block is supposed to be at the first row/first column.  It only shows the 1 x 1 component occupying the first row/first column.